# Laughed at a Kafir joke

Tags: tawba, kufr

I was listening to my friends talking about some game and at one point one of them shouted "praise the great powers". I laughed a little at that, but soon I began to wonder if I had left Islam.

Is it Kufr?

And two more questions that I would also like an answer to:

**1)** Is it kufr if I tell people that I may have committed kufr (such as now)?

**2)** will Allah accept the tawbah of someone who made fun of religion? Because I have read several times somewhere that such a person's tawba will not be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Uttering phrases like "praise the great powers" in a game context does **NOT** constitute Kufr, unless one genuinely **believes** in powers other than Allah.

It is crucial to differentiate between **playful remarks** and **actual disbelief**.

And Tawbah(repentance) is always open to sincere believers, regardless of past actions.